# How to change the value of an index in a list that exist in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

I have a list like named as modified and can be seen below;

`modified = [["a"]*3]*3`

If I want to change the value of first index in first element with "1", I use the codeblock below;

`modified[0][0] = int(1)`

However, the result is shown as `[[1, 'a', 'a'], [1, 'a', 'a'], [1, 'a', 'a']]`.

I was expecting the result as `[[1, 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: My bet, you created `modified` using `modified = [['a', 'a', 'a']]*3` or similar

Comment: It looks like you added the same list `['a', 'a', 'a']` three times to the list `modified`. Could please show how you really create the outer list?

Comment: Are you sure you are declaring `modified` the same way you mentioned in your code?

Comment: Yes, it was created with [["a"]*3]*3

Comment: Then you have 3 times the **same** sublist in your outer list